# How do I search the number of occurrences of individual words in text data?

Tags: r, loops, apply

How do I find the count of occurrences of a list of words? I can search for one word as follows:

```
dplyr::filter(data, grepl("apple", data$content,ignore.case = TRUE))
length(x$content)
```

The `|`separator allows me to sum up all occurrences. But I want to count each word individually.

The words could be supplied as a row in a csv or written as a vector in R itself, e.g.:

```
words <- c("apple","orange","pear","pineapple")
```

One wrinkle is that the `data$count` are a column of tweets so the word can occur more than once per tweet. So I'd like to count only if they occur in the row.

Comment: See `stringr::str_count`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get `logical` values for the presence/absence of your target words like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

words <- c("apple","orange","pear","pineapple")

data <- tibble(content = c("Ony my grocery list are green apples, red apples and oranges",
                           "My favorite froyo flavors are pineapple, peach-pear and pear"))

boundary_words <- paste0("\\b", words) # if you want to avoid counting the apple in pineapple

map_dfc(boundary_words, ~ as.tibble(grepl(., data$content))) %>%
    set_names(words) %>%
    bind_cols(data, .)

# A tibble: 2 x 5
                                                       content apple orange  pear pineapple
                                                         <chr> <lgl>  <lgl> <lgl>     <lgl>
1 Ony my grocery list are green apples, red apples and oranges  TRUE   TRUE FALSE     FALSE
2 My favorite froyo flavors are pineapple, peach-pear and pear FALSE  FALSE  TRUE      TRUE
```

Comment: Great, thank you. One extension I added was to name the object `newdata` and count the number of 'TRUE's in the relevant column with `apply(X=newdata[9:12],2,FUN=function(x) length(which(x=='TRUE')))`

Answer (score 0):

Using the `stringr` package...

```
library(stringr)
words <- c("apple","orange","pear","pineapple")

data <- c("On my grocery list are green apples, red apples and oranges",
          "Oranges are my favourite, but I also like pineapples and pearls")

sapply(words,function(w) 
       str_count(str_to_lower(str_split(data," ")), #split into words and set to lower case
                 paste0("\\b",w,"s*\\b"))) #adds word boundaries and optional plural -s

     apple orange pear pineapple
[1,]     2      1    0         0
[2,]     0      1    0         1

This allows for capital letters, and should only count whole words (perhaps with an -s plural).
```